# Is the Zoom H4n supposed to make metal clinching sounds?

Tags: microphone

I just got the Zoom H4n and did a test recording. You can hear a metallic clinching noise all the time if you don't put it on a table. There is considerably less clinching noises if you have the wind screen on, so I suspect it is because of something loose or similar in the microphones. Is it supposed to be like this, or can I change it and get one without these sounds?

Here is a sample I made. It is the 18. recording made by the H4n. http://snd.sc/zq85xa
Here is the same clip uploaded to YouTube:

The right channel makes these metal sounds once in a while, not very loud, but the left channel makes a lot of them, loud, all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like I tap the microphone, but I don't..

Comment: I have a Tascam DR08, and this is the same sound I get if I hand hold it. You can't hand hold these things without picking up your grip, movements etc. Treat the recorder like it's a one big mic, or since it's stereo, two big mics.

Comment: Thanks, then the problem is solved! How do you treat a big mic? Do you mean mounting it onto the tripod mount? (The short stick with a 1/4' screw that came with it.) It at least solves the problem for me, especially when combined with the wind muff!

Comment: (You can add this as an answer if you want) :)

Comment: How to treat one big mic? the key word here is isolation. You want to keep the a mic mechanically isolated from any vibration other than the sound(s) you want recorded. Mic stands, pop screens, wind screens, shock mounts come to mind.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll look a bit more into the shock mount.

Comment: I owned an H4n for a couple of years and it did not have the metallic ringing sound in either mic. The sound of handling the recorder was there but no ringing from either mic. Unfortunately my H4n was stolen. I bought a replacement and immediately noticed the ringing sounds. In this case it is the mic for the right channel. Granted you hear the ringing along with handling noise, but the ringing is at a particular pitch and I fear that I'll wind up with sympathetic resonance issues at the same pitch on the right channel when recording program material. The left channel is fine. I am exchanging

Comment: This is a followup on my last post here. I had a brand new H4n with the metallic ringing problem on the right channel and I promptly exchanged it for another brand new unit. The exchange unit has no metallic ringing problem. Both mics are fine. So the answer to the question is: No- The ZOOM H4n is NOT supposed to make metallic ringing or clinking sounds. Handling noise is normal but should not be accompanied by ringing or clinking in the mic capsules.

Comment: Did it sound like what I've recorded?

Comment: Hmm, but is this microphone actually broken, as yours was? Or is it just handling noise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely handling noise. I'm not a big fan of the little handle that came with the thing, so I jury rigged a mount 1/4" - 3/8" - 5/8"...the first is a standard tripod screw mount adapter, the second is a mic stand adapter. I epoxied them together so they don't make noise, added an o-ring at the 1/4" end to minimize noise at the h4n, and I've got the 5/8" end screwed to a table mic stand.

For handheld, I can unscrew the post from the base, wrap a foam handlebar grip around it, and viola...no noise. 3/8" female is also standard for boom poles...if you want to have your h4n on a boom.

Whatever you do, make sure you have an assortment of neoprene or rubber washers...they go a long way to minimizing sound at the connecting points.

Other solutions: I've got a tripod quick release mounting plate I can screw to the back, then set it on a tripod...hands-free = no handling noise.

One of the other miracle things is a fig-rig clamp. 3/8 AND 1/4 screws, and the inside of the clamp is lined with cork or rubber. You can clamp it to anything in the 3/4" to 1" range...lightstands, c-stands, broompoles for a cheap boom-pole...very versatile!

Adapters: 
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/554344-REG/Manfrotto_120_120_Converter_Plate_for.html

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/305934-REG/AKG_KM216_BLACK_3_8_Male_to_5_8_.html

Stand:
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/154670-REG/K_M_23200_500_55_Table_Top_Microphone_Stand.html

Fig-Rig Clamp
http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/381895-REG/Manfrotto_595CLA_595CLA_Fig_Rig_Clamp.html